# Determine if a graph with the following characteristics exists or not

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

1. A graph of order 13 where the vertices $v_1,...,v_{13}$ have the following degrees: $v_i$ has degree $3$ if $i$ is odd, $4$ if $i$ is even
2. A graph of order 12 where the vertices $v_1,...,v_{12}$ have the following degrees: $v_i$ has degree $1$ if $i$ is odd, $2$ if $i$ is even

I tried to answer this question by simply using the handshaking lemma.

1. Between 1 and 13 there are seven odd numbers which mean seven vertices that have odd degrees. By the lemma, we know that in a graph there is an even number of vertices which have an odd degree. The graph doesn't exist.
2. Using the same reasoning a graph of this type should exist.

Could you confirm if my reasoning is correct? If correct, is it sufficient to answer the question or should I include additional proof?

Comment: Standard mathematical English is "degree" for the number of edges at a vertex, not "grade". Is this translated from another language?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake it was an oversight. Now I've corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handshake lemma works well for showing that a list of degrees is impossible, but it's a one-way implication. Your part (1) is good, but your reasoning for part (2) simply doesn't prove anything. For example, a list of degrees $4,4,4,0,0,0$ on six vertices satisfies the handshake lemma condition, but there is no such graph.

For part (2), the best way to prove such a graph exists is to explicitly construct such a graph.

Comment: In fact, the main problem with the second question was being able to try to draw the graph, if it actually exists. I drew this (https://imgur.com/a/P82DeBj), could it be the graph required?

Comment: That is indeed one such graph. They're not hard to find.